# Error action continue in catch block

Tags: powershell

My supervisor at work said to always use `ErrorAction -Continue` in a catch block:

```
workflow foo {

try {
    Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Product  | ? {$_.Vendor -eq 'Google Inc.'}
    }

catch {
    Write-Error "Something went wrong." -ErrorAction Continue
    Throw
    }
}
```

What is the benefit of using `-EA Continue` here? It serves no purpose - throw is executed next and terminates the script anyway.

In both functions and workflows. Is my supervisor correct?

Comment: `Throw` in `catch` block will rethrow original exception, which likely would be more useful than generic `"Something went wrong."` message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking that `-EA Continue` was used with `Write-Error` in this case to make sure that  the following `Throw` gets executed even if the `$ErrorActionPreference` of the scope was changed to `Stop`.

Now, that at least is the behaviour in functions.

Workflows seem to be different. I was testing your example with the `$ErrorActionPreference` set to `Stop` and `1/0` in the `try` block to create an exception:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 1
workflow foo 
{

    try 
    {
         1/0
    }

    catch 
    {
        Write-Error "Something went wrong." -ErrorAction Continue
        Throw
    }
}
```

Regardless of the `-EA Continue` in the line before the `Throw` doesn't get excecuted in this case. So the `$ErrorActionPreference` in workflows seems to overwrite any per-cmdlet settings, that are done by the `-EA` parameter.

As I said, this behaviour is different with functions:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 1
function bar 
{

    try 
    {
         1/0
    }

    catch 
    {
        Write-Error "Something went wrong." -ErrorAction Continue
        Throw
    }
}
```

Here the `-ErrorAction Continue` makes the difference of the `Throw` being executed or not.

By the way: if you also want to consider the case that the `$ErrorActionPreference` was set to `SilentlyContinue` (and you are not using workflows) than you may want to replace your `Throw` with `Write-Error $_ -EA Continue` otherwise your `Throw` would just silently continue.

So in short: It seems that the `-EA` parameter is of no effect in your workflow example, if your idea is to be independent of the current `$ErrorActionPreference`. In functions it makes sense, but in that case the `Throw` statement should also be avoided.